# How to create thread listen server through cocoaasyncsocket in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoaasyncsocket

How to create thread to listen server through `cocoaasyncsocket` in ios app

I am using `cocoaasyncSocket` from here: [cocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

i try sample code and push this code into `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m`
but when i am connected, this app don't receive any data send from server.
I want my app auto receive data from server after connected

Comment: May i can using nstimer to make request to server every second?

Answer (score 0):

To receive data from the other peer of the socket you should call a read method. It can be `readDataWithTimeout`. When you receive data from server `- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag` delegate method will be fired.

Comment: i put method in appdelegate.. is that true?...but i seem nothing to fired when server push data back

Comment: I think, you should first try with cocoaAsyncSocket's connectTest sample. Try to make proper changes to connect to your server.